# Unknown Dremel bits -Need to identify

Tags: drill, drill-bit, dremel

Any idea what these Dremel 3000 bits or parts do? I bought a second-hand used Dremel 3000, these bits came along with it. The cylinder shape bit (A in the picture) feels hard rubber/tyre and the Rounded Bit (C in the picture) feels hard but very light, unlike stone/any metal

The second question- how to connect the shaft ("B" in the picture) with the Dremel Shaft/Collet Nut, the thread of a Dremel shaft and this (B) is of different width. This adapter can be used to connect different Bigger Bits/Drum/Disk etc.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The part labeled  "B" is  I believe  unrelated to the Dremel KIt. It looks more like a mountain bike  "V" brake mounting  post.  It is possible that the dremel was used to remove the screw. A is a cylindracal grinder that has been  used , that resulted in the bevel in the side,

Comment: May I submit that the simplest answer is to simply go out and buy a new kit of bits (which may also come with new collets, which would be a good thing to replace if worn) and start with those, rather than trying to get by with ancient bits that have seen better days? Bits are disposable components.

Comment: @keshlam I bought two separate accessories (2 different kits) for Dremel, I just want to know what these bits do, not that I need them right now, just want to know.

Comment: @mikes I think that "B" is/can be used to attach different Bigger Grinding/Sanding Disk/Drum. As in the picture here - https://pasteboard.co/78YkmqI4JXHf.png

Comment: @mikes And the groove in "A" is very symmetrical and uniform, doesnt look like shaped by usage.

Comment: E is completely caked up.  You can't even see the abrading surface.

Comment: If the groove in A was caused by it being used (which I agree with), then it's no surprise that it's symmetrical and uniform. It would have been worn down in the same way that a workpiece in a lathe is shaped.

Comment: @brhans the reason I doubted "A" being shaped by usage is it feels very soft, u can pinch hard with a fingernail, it doesnt feel like a hard abrading surface. Its feels more of a polishing kinda thing to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A should be a used grinding/sanding bit.

B is an accessory to mount probably larger disks.

C is a grinding/sanding disk.

D is just odd.

E should be a wood grinding tool with protective coating still on.

Comment: I believe that D is part of a sanding-drum bit.

Comment: Thank u very much, what kind of grinding/sanding is "A" and "C" for? I mean wood, metal, masonry? BTW, "E" feels like hard stone with coarse grain.

Comment: Grinding: Yes, with varying degrees of success. Less effective on wood because they tend to clog, reasonably effective on many metals, sometimes effective on masonry. Sounds like E is also a grinding bit, coarser cutting, might work better on wood. Really, your best bet is comparing them with parts in the new kits.

Comment: @keshlam Thanks actually the new kit doesnt have any of this.  The "A" feels very soft, u can pinch hard with a fingernail, it doesnt feel like a hard abrading surface. Its feels more of a polishing kinda thing to me. The "C" is a very light and thin material, not soft but light.